# How to calculate $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\cdots(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

I have a combinatorics problem and I've reduced it to finding coefficient that stands with $x^n$ in this polynomial,

$$(1+x)(1+x+x^2)...(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)$$

But now I'm stuck. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Another way to state the problem would be to find the product of all terms of $$\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$$ as $k$ varies from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: I found this: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/MARGOLIUS/inversions.pdf

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372991/number-of-n-element-permutations-with-exactly-k-inversions

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, $k$ needs to go to $n+1$ in your formulation.

Comment: @Paul Minor error, you're right; unfortunately I can't edit my account.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a row in the table of **Mahonian numbers.**

Here they are: Sloane's [A008302](https://oeis.org/A008302).

That link gives you lots and lots of other links and references, and it includes a recurrence for calculating them (which I added a couple of years ago). Here, $T(1,)$ represents $1$ and $T(2,)$ represents $(1+x)$, etc.

$$T(1, 1) = 1,\qquad T(1, k\neq 1) = 0,\\
T(n, k) = T(n, k-1) + T(n-1, k) - T(n-1, k-n),\\
\text{or }T(n, k) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\ T(n-1, k-j),\\$$

Answer (score 2):

This product gives the Poincare series for the symmetric group $S_{n+1}$ considered as a Coxeter group of type $A_n$. The answer is therefore the number of permutations in $S_{n+1}$ that can be minimally expressed as a product of $n$ adjacent transpositions. I think this is likely the best formula you will find for this number.